# How to get list of files which were updated today? .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, file-upload

I have thousands of files in a FTP server which I can connect using windows explorer. Day by day, during evening, I have to find the files which were changed (uploaded) today and take their name.
I'd like to develop a visual basic batch application that, just running the EXE with a parameter (date), take a list of the names of those files.

Recently I found this code here:

```
source = "\\ftp_my\Upload\"
searchfor = "*"
Dim dirs As String() = Directory.GetFiles(source, searchfor)
For Each file In dirs
    fileinfo = New FileInfo(file)
    If (fileinfo.LastWriteTime >= DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -1, Date.Today)) Then
        'execute my actions
    End If
Next
```

But it takes an increditable time to list all files and evaluate their properties. On the other hand , if I just make a "dir", export to excel, split the text and evaluate manually the date / files I want I finish that study earlier than the VB!

Therefore there should be a command that list the files ordered by date DESC during a resonable period, is there?

Comment: Is the only difference between your two scenarios that you don't have the `If` statement in one?

Comment: How long does the "execute my actions" in your code take?

Comment: My action is just write the filename and the date in a C:\TEMP folder.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of thing I noticed that can slow your iteration down.

You're casting each file name to a fileinfo object instead of using a collection of fileinfo objects.

You're calculating the target date to check for, for each file, instead of calculating it once.

Here's a method to do what you want using LINQ that will find 1000 files(worst case scenario), on a mapped network drive, in less than 5 seconds:

```
    Dim source = New DirectoryInfo("\\ftp_my\Upload\")
    Dim searchfor = "*"
    Dim TargetDate = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -1, Date.Today)
    Dim dirs = (From f As FileInfo In source.GetFiles(searchfor)
                Where f.CreationTime >= TargetDate
                Select f).ToList
```

dirs will contain all the fileinfo objects for each file you want to target.

If iterating through dirs and completing your actions on each file takes a long time then this will tell you where the time is being spent, and you can start looking at that code and start optimizing it to cut down the time.

Comment: Well tinstaafl, I tried your suggestion and for listing 4300 files , using you solution, I got 36 minutes - this is not so different than the previous one. Peharps the issue is the network connection, though I don't understand why it happens for such a basic information like that. In addition the "action" I take is just write the file names to c:\temp -- therefore it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Moreover: _Here's a method to do what you want using LINQ that will find 1000 files(worst case scenario), on a mapped network drive, in less than 5 seconds:_
The service account that I am using cannot created network drives, therefore I have to use the **\\ftp_asd\Upload** , of course, you understand that I should not publish the correct address.

Comment: Yes.  That info was just to show what circumstances I got my results with.  Since you're accessing the files over a network you should have been able to get similar results.  Your problem is probably with the network.  Try and calculate your throughput, how much data you're transferring over so much time, and compare that with data transfers with other sites.